# Why is the voltage drop being used to calculate the current?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

I need some more help with explaining an example. I'm having trouble understanding [this part](https://makeabilitylab.github.io/physcomp/electronics/leds.html#step-3-solve-for-current-i) of a tutorial, and my question is fairly simple. Why use the voltage drop rather than the battery voltage to calculate the current? Or anything else for that matter such as the 9V - 8.3V, which is 0.7V.

Comment: Even with the link and the three sentences you wrote I'm not sure I understand your confusion, yet. Why use the battery voltage when there is a diode in series?

Comment: In this circuit we assume that the battery can deliver ample current and that the diode would allow a large current to flow, so the component that limits the current us the resistor, and then use Ohm’s law to work out what that current is.  Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current in this simple loop is the same in all components. Unless we split it up and insert a current meter, we must look for a component, where we know its resistance and the voltage across it. Then we can calculate I = U/R. We don't know the resistance of the diode and it is a dynamic resistance. We also don't know the voltage drop in the battery and the internal resistance. The resistor is the only component we can use for the calculation.